# How to process multi-arm studies with netmeta?

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I'm a researcher in NYC looking for help with the *netmeta* function (I'm using v. 2.1-0 in order to be compatible with the guide [listed here](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/netwma.html#bayesian-network-meta-analysis-in-r)).

When I run the function *netmeta* on my data-set with the following arguments (comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE, reference.group = "PLA",) I get this error:

```
Error: Problems in multi-arm studies!

- Studies with inconsistent treatment estimates: 'Azorin.2013', 'Landbloom.2016', 'McIntyre.2009'
- Study with negative treatment arm variance: 'Azorin.2013'
- Please check original data used as input to netmeta().
- Argument 'tol.multiarm' in netmeta() can be used to relax consistency
  assumption for multi-arm studies (if appropriate).
  In addition: Warning message:
  Matrix inversion resulted in negative variances for multi-arm study 'Azorin.2013'.
  Consider changing argument 'func.inverse', e.g., ginv() from MASS package.
```

First of all, here is an excerpt of my original data set (Azorin being a multi-arm study, Berwaerts being a single-arm study):

| studylab | grp1n | grp1m | grp1sd | grp2n | grp2m | grp2sd | treat1 | treat2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Azorin.2013 | 107 | -15.00 | .90000 | 33.0 | -11.50 | 1.200000 | ASE | PLA |
| Azorin.2013 | 12 | -13.3 | 0.9000 | 33.0 | -11.50 | 1.200000 | OLA | PLA |
| Azorin.2013 | 107 | -15.00 | 0.90000 | 122.0 | -13.30 | 0.900000 | ASE | OLA |
| Berwaerts.2012 | 39 | -13.10 | 8.32000 | 36.0 | -10.80 | 9.420000 | PAL | PLA |

Then I calculated the effect sizes using the following formula:

```
effect_sizes_YMRS <- effect_sizes(YMRS_09_10, study=studylab, grp1m = grp1m, grp2m = grp2m, 
                                  grp1sd = grp1sd, grp2sd = grp2sd, 
                                  grp1n = grp1n, grp2n = grp2n, fun = "esc_mean_sd")
```

which I then extracted/transformed resulting in data-set freq_YMRS:

| study | es | se | treat1 | treat2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Azorin.2013 | -3.57947512 | 0.2922469 | ASE | PLA |
| Azorin.2013 | -1.85481799 | 0.2227053 | OLA | PLA |
| Azorin.2013 | -1.85481799 | 0.2227053 | OLA | PLA |
| Berwaerts.2012 | -0.25946344 | 0.2320940 | PALX | PLA |

Even so when I run the main function netmeta, I still get the errors listed above. I have tried playing around with the tol.multiarm function but to no avail.

```
ymrs.netmeta <- netmeta(TE = es,
                     seTE = se,
                     treat1 = treat1,
                     treat2 = treat2,
                     studlab = study,
                     data = effect_sizes_YMRS,
                     sm = "SMD",
                     comb.fixed = FALSE,
                     comb.random = TRUE,
                     reference.group = "PLA",
                     details.chkmultiarm = TRUE,
                     sep.trts = " vs ",
                     )
```